# Creating a VBA Macro in excel for a Mailmerge

Tags: excel, vba, mailmerge

I have created a vba macro by putting bits and pieces together and the code runs but does not deliver what it is supposed to deliver. Macro Runs, it says its complete but does not actually give me the document for mail merge PDF or DOC

I've looked all over the place, I've tried to step through it. It's like it just skips the mail merge part.

```
Sub MailMergeToPDF()
    Dim wdApp As Object ' Word.Application
    Dim wdDoc As Object ' Word.Document
    Dim SourcePath As String
    Dim SavePath As String
    Dim i As Long

    ' Set the file paths
    SourcePath = "C:\Users\username\Documents\Notice Template.docx"
    SavePath = "C:\Users\username\Documents\Notice Folder"

    ' Create a new instance of Word
    On Error Resume Next
    Set wdApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
    On Error GoTo 0

    If wdApp Is Nothing Then
        Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    End If

    ' Disable Word alerts to avoid prompts
    wdApp.DisplayAlerts = False

    ' Loop through the Excel data and perform the mail merge
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MailMerge Sheet") ' Change "Sheet1" to the actual name of your Excel data sheet
        For i = 2 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row ' Assuming data starts from row 2
            ' Open the Word document template
            Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open(SourcePath)

            ' Replace tokens in the Word document with data from Excel
            With wdDoc.Content.Find
                .Text = "<<Today>>" ' Replace this with your token in the Word document
                .Replacement.Text = .Cells(i, 1).Value ' Assuming the data for the first name is in column A
                .Wrap = 1 ' wdFindContinue
                .Execute Replace:=2 ' wdReplaceAll
            End With

            ' Add other token replacements here following the same pattern as above
            With wdDoc.Content.Find
                .Text = "<<Employee_Name>>" ' Replace this with the token for last name in the Word document
                .Replacement.Text = .Cells(i, 2).Value ' Assuming the data for the last name is in column B
                .Wrap = 1 ' wdFindContinue
                .Execute Replace:=2 ' wdReplaceAll
            End With
            
            ' Add other token replacements here following the same pattern as above
            With wdDoc.Content.Find
                .Text = "<<Vacation_Used>>" ' Replace this with the token for last name in the Word document
                .Replacement.Text = .Cells(i, 3).Value ' Assuming the data for the last name is in column B
                .Wrap = 1 ' wdFindContinue
                .Execute Replace:=2 ' wdReplaceAll
            End With

            ' Save the merged document as PDF with a specific title based on Excel data
            Dim PDFFileName As String
            PDFFileName = "Name of Document " & .Cells(i, 2).Value ' Combine first name and last name to form the PDF title
            wdDoc.ExportAsFixedFormat SavePath & PDFFileName & ".pdf", 17 ' 17 is wdExportFormatPDF

            ' Close the Word document
            wdDoc.Close SaveChanges:=False
        Next i
    End With

    ' Quit Word
    wdApp.Quit

    ' Clean up
    Set wdDoc = Nothing
    Set wdApp = Nothing

    ' Inform the user that the process is completed
    MsgBox "Mail Merge and PDF creation completed successfully!", vbInformation
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you actually stepped through the code to see what is happening? What did it do. Plus - without knowing what data you have on that sheet - it does look as if it ignores the loop

Comment: I have stepped through, it skips through the whole replacement.

Comment: See *Run a Mailmerge from Excel, Sending the Output to Individual Files* in the **Mailmerge Tips and Tricks** page at:
https://www.msofficeforums.com/mail-merge/21803-mailmerge-tips-tricks.html

Comment: Move the `MsgBox ...` command line after the `wdDoc.ExportAsFixedFormat ...` line that will mean that a file was created.

Answer (score 0):

Add a backslash to the pathname

```
   SavePath = "C:\Users\username\Documents\Notice Folder\"
```

to get a valid filename.

Didn't see the error message because of `DisplayAlerts=False`

Comment: I added the backslash, still auto complete and no document appears. i also removed or comment out Displayalerts=false.

Comment: Insert after this line `Dim PDFFileName As String` the following: `Debug.Print  "Message:" , wdDoc.Fullname, wdDoc.path`. In the immediate window you have to see the loaded filename and the path to it. If either or both not displayed you don't declare a valid filename when loading it, but in this case you would have to get an error message.

Answer (score 0):

If your data is not in Column A of that sheet then the loop becomes

```
For i = 2 to 1
```

and so will not execute anything inside the loop. Solution - be more explict with your range.

If there is data in column A of that sheet then the text `<<Today>>`, `<<Employee_Name>>` and `<<Vacation_Used>>` are not present in the document. Solution - make sure you are opening the correct document and that you have got the correct placeholder text in place e.g. `<<` and not `<`

When you come to save the PDF you will get another error - to fix that, see the solution from Black cat.

Fix all those and your code works

Comment: We are making some progress, now I am stuck at .Replacement.Text = .Cells(i, 2).Value

Should I be setting my document has a mail merge prior to the macro? Current it is a set up as a mail merge. I have column heads and the information starting in row 2

Comment: That line worked fine for me. I don't know what "stuck at" means.  This is straightforward text replacement - setting up the document as MailMerge wouldn't have any effect